# Same code in one project works, fails in 2nd project: Thread 1: "-[Destini_iOS13.ViewController IBAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: swift

I'm brand new to Swift programming. I'm doing a Udemy project and have copied all the exact same code from their "completed" project (which builds and runs fine) into my "learning" project and it fails with error:

Thread 1: "-[Destini_iOS13.ViewController IBAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15ff0c250"

It's a very simple program and I have no idea why the identical code works in one but not the other. Is this some broken link or resource? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a button in `Main.storyboard` is linked to a method not in the `ViewController` class.

To fix this -

1. Right click on the button within the storyboard file to bring up a list of links/connections to it.
2. Remove all items listed under `Sent Events` (I'm assuming it's just the item listed for `Touch Up Inside`, but remove others as well if they're there)
3. Right-click and drag from the button to inside the `ViewController` file:

   - If the `@IBAction` function you want's already listed, drag over it until it's highlighted.
   - If you want to create a new `@IBAction` function, drag it to an empty line inside the `ViewController` class.

Comment: Thank you sir. This allows the app to run. For my education, there were 2 links in each of the button's pop-ups. I'm assuming that at some point I pasted in new code and relinked the same button but didn't delete the original. Or, will these links break if I change a variable name in the IBAction line and then revert to the original variable name after? Finally, the app still exits after time with a Thread 1: signal SIGTERM error. Is this somehow related?